# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.persistence.AttributeConverter

Tags: hibernate, jpa, websphere

I have an EAR file with

1. class loader set to PARENT_LAST and
2. hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar packaged with in the EAR itself.

Still while deployment to Websphere BPM 8.5.5 I am getting the NoClassDefFoundError. The stack trace goes as below

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.persistence.AttributeConverter
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:94)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:171)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.hibernate.impl.SessionManagerImpl$1.run(SessionManagerImpl.java:114)
```

Has anybody faced this issue earlier or fixed it?

Comment: Your container has another JPA API jar in the CLASSPATH and that is being found, not JPA API v2.1. The error message says it all

Answer (score 1):

The stack of the nested ClassNotFoundException would tell us with more certainty (it should include the actual loaders being used for the failed class load), but Billy's comment is almost certainly on the right track.  You've added some custom class, which depends on the JPA API, to the server's JVM class path (or, possibly, to the boot class path or a directory in java.ext.dirs, like java/jre/lib/ext; the effect would be the same, though).

Putting something in the JVM class path causes it to be loaded by the Java application loader, which is the parent to all other class loaders in the environment, including the OSGi loader that picks up most of WebSphere's runtime.  Because of that, it can't "see" any WebSphere classes, including core stuff like the Java EE APIs.

Custom classes basically never belong in the JVM class path on a WebSphere server.  Shared libraries are the usual recommendation for that (assuming there's some reason why you can't just leave it in your application), and there's an Extension Class Loader on the server, populated by a few directories like WAS_HOME/lib/ext, that can be used if you have stuff like custom security modules that needs to be visible to the server outside of application scope.